# Unity Slow Motion but not the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

i want to achieve slow motion in Unity but the player should stay on normal speed.

Here's my code:

```
    float powerUpDuration = 5;           // Slow down for 5 sec
    float slowMotionTimeScale = 0.5f;    // Slow down by half
    float defaultTimeScale = 1;          // default time speed

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") // Player collides with powerup
        {
            Time.timeScale = slowMotionTimeScale;   // Time get's slowed
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.timeScale;   // Smooth slow down
            InvokeRepeating("SpeedManager", 0, 1);   // Powerup Timer

            movementspeed = ... // My missing code...

        }
    }

    void SpeedManager()
    {
        if (powerUpDuration > 0)   // as long as time is left ...
        {
            powerUpDuration--;     // Countdown Timer
        }
        else      // Timer is on 0
        {
            CancelInvoke("SpeedManager");        // Stop counting
            Time.timeScale = defaultTimeScale;   // Set Time speed to default
            powerUpDuration = 5;       // reset timer

            movementspeed = ... // Reset movementspeed to default
        }
    }
```

The only thing is, that i am struggling on setting the speed..

Does someone knows how to handle the timescaling on movementspeed?

Comment: I don't really get what's your problem : simply dividing base `movementSpeed` value by `slowMotionTimeScale` should be enough ?

Comment: Try multiply movementSpeed on Time.timeScale.